# Delete IMG atributes from database

Tags: notepad++

I have database with lot of image references inside.
I'm planning to upgrade my CMS, and I'd like to keep existing images in articles. However, I'd like to get rid of image attributes "height" and "width".

Here is how one of IMG references looks like:

```
<img alt="" src="http://www.urltomysite.com/images/image.jpg" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-right: 5px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px; width: 150px; height: 223px; " />
```

What I would like to remove from this or similar codes is "height" and "width" attributes. Attributes are not same through database.
However there are some DIVs where I would like to keep "height" and "width" attributes.

I already successfully removed SPAN html tags (and its content) with Notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove them using regex.

Replacing this

```
(height|width):.*?;
```

with an empty string should work

Using notepad++, you should press ctrl+f, choose 'replace' tab, choose search mode 'Regular expression' and replace them all.

Comment: Thanks, that is nice and it works. However, there is also an attribute called "line-height" which is also included in regex search. Is it possible somehow to exclude it from search, or to tell regex that we are looking exactly for "height"?

Comment: Sure, try this 
[^-](height|width):.*?;

Comment: Thanks, Janar. It works. 
Also, I replaced column sign (:) with (=) where CSS attribute is set with =.